# Using RegEx, how do I record conversions for specific URLs and not others?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to have Google Analytics record a goal when a user lands on a specific page. My client's sales funnel uses dynamic parameters within the URL as you can see below. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to fire a goal when a user lands on /2eR54 and not when they land on /confirm.

**Goal:** /booking/SDFG/2eR54

Not Goal: /booking/SDFG/confirm

Quick notes: The first dynamic field is always four capitalized letters; the second dynamic parameter is a combination of digits and capitalized and non-capitalized letters.

I've tried using the following but /confirm still fires a conversion: .*/booking/[A-Z]{4}/[0-9A-Za-z]{5}

I appreciate your help with this matter.

Comment: Generic regex `\/booking\/[A-Z]{4}\/\w+` | Specific regex `\/booking\/[A-Z]{4}\/2eR54` | [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OyF8SO/1/)

Comment: Is the length of the second parameter exactly 5 characters?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The second parameter will be 5 characters for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @NickReed, I've tried a similar regular expression and the /confirm is still getting recorded. 
https://regex101.com/r/OyF8SO/2

Comment: [`\/booking\/[A-Z]{4}\/\w{5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/OyF8SO/3)

Comment: @NickReed Looks like that did it!

Add it as an answer so you can get credit.

Comment: I was using .*/booking/[A-Z]{4}/[0-9A-Za-z]{5} before.

Comment: Why am I getting negative votes for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `\/booking\/[A-Z]{4}\/\w{5}$` may fit your needs.

It matches `/booking/`, four capital letters, `/`, and then 5 word characters, followed by the end of the string. (If this URL won't be at the end of the string, you may also be able to use `\b`, the word boundary.)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OyF8SO/3)

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to upvote / accept the answer if it addresses your question!